# Non-type parameter pack cartesian product, "template argument deduction/substitution failed"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, c++20

I was messing with non-type parameter packs and tried to do a cartesian product with them. I arrived at a piece of code that somehow compiles with GCC in C++20 but not C++17, and does not compile with Clang at all. I also tried MSVC, which, like GCC, compiles in C++20 but not C++17, but also generates a lot of assembly code for some reason.

I would like to understand why the code doesn't compile in C++17. The error message isn't useful, it just says `template argument deduction/substitution failed:` and the line in question...

Here is the simplest snippet I could come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<auto ...values>
struct ValueParameterPack {};

template<std::size_t I, typename T, T ...values>
constexpr T get(ValueParameterPack<values...>) {
    constexpr T value_array[] = {values...};
    return value_array[I];
}

template<std::size_t I, typename T>
constexpr auto get_v = get<I>(T{});

template<auto ...values1, auto ...values2, std::size_t ...Is>
auto cartesian_product(ValueParameterPack<values1...>, ValueParameterPack<values2...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> ValueParameterPack<
        std::make_pair(
            get_v<Is / sizeof...(values2), ValueParameterPack<values1...>>,
            get_v<Is % sizeof...(values2), ValueParameterPack<values2...>>
        )...
    >;

template<auto ...values1, auto ...values2>
auto cartesian_product(ValueParameterPack<values1...>, ValueParameterPack<values2...>)
    -> decltype(cartesian_product(
        ValueParameterPack<values1...>{},
        ValueParameterPack<values2...>{},
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(values1) * sizeof...(values2)>()
    ));

template<typename ValueParameterPack1, typename ValueParameterPack2>
using CartesianProduct = decltype(cartesian_product(ValueParameterPack1{}, ValueParameterPack2{}));

int main() {
    using T = CartesianProduct<ValueParameterPack<1, 2>, ValueParameterPack<3, 4>>;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sWGv7G7e5

Here is a longer version that actually makes use of the cartesian product in case you're curious, but it's not very important: https://godbolt.org/z/dnYbKMe18

I'm sure there are other ways to achieve what I want, and I welcome any idea, but I'm mostly just curious as to why GCC can compile it with `-std=c++20` but not with `std=c++17`, since I don't think I'm using any C++20 feature. And I want some insights into that error message that provides no additional details.

Comment: error: ‘std::pair<int, int>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter because it is not structural - you can't pass a pair as a template argument

Comment: @lorro Did you get that error from a compiler? If so, how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write,

```
ValueParameterPack<
        std::make_pair(
            get_v<Is / sizeof...(values2), ValueParameterPack<values1...>>,
            get_v<Is % sizeof...(values2), ValueParameterPack<values2...>>
        )...
    >;
```

you can't pass a `std::pair` as a template non-type argument. You can, however, pass it as *two arguments* (if the particular types allow it). So I'd recommend to pass, instead of a `ValueParameterPack<pair<int,int>(..)...>`, passing a `ValueParameterPack<int, int, ...>`. Then process it by every pair of element. If you don't like the idea of processing two elements as a step, I've included a workaround solution below using compile-time pairs.

To be clear, when I write, 'can't pass', I don't mean it according to the C++ standard. It's an error message that occurs with g++. Likely a compiler / library issue. While debugging your code, there were at minimum 2 similar issues, so it's not something that never occurs - likely worth reporting.

---

Here's a way to solve it without `std::pair<>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<auto i, auto j>
struct mypair {};

template<auto ...values>
struct ValueParameterPack {};

template<std::size_t I, typename T, T ...values>
constexpr T get(ValueParameterPack<values...>) {
    constexpr T value_array[] = {values...};
    return value_array[I];
}

template<std::size_t I, typename T>
constexpr auto get_v = get<I>(T{});

template<size_t I, size_t C, typename T1, typename T2>
using mypair_gen =
    mypair<
        get_v<I / C, T1>,
        get_v<I % C, T2>
    >;

template<auto ...values1, auto ...values2, std::size_t ...Is>
auto cartesian_product(ValueParameterPack<values1...>, ValueParameterPack<values2...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> ValueParameterPack<
        mypair_gen<Is, sizeof...(values2), ValueParameterPack<values1...>, ValueParameterPack<values2...>>{}...
    >;

template<auto ...values1, auto ...values2>
auto cartesian_product(ValueParameterPack<values1...>, ValueParameterPack<values2...>)
    -> decltype(cartesian_product(
        ValueParameterPack<values1...>{},
        ValueParameterPack<values2...>{},
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(values1) * sizeof...(values2)>()
    ));

template<typename ValueParameterPack1, typename ValueParameterPack2>
using CartesianProduct = decltype(cartesian_product(ValueParameterPack1{}, ValueParameterPack2{}));

int main() {
    using T = CartesianProduct<ValueParameterPack<1, 2>, ValueParameterPack<3, 4>>;
}
```

Comment: I see, but then why does it work in C++20? Is it supposed to? Was there a change to `std::pair` or to what one can pass as template non-type arguments?

Comment: `pair<int, int>` is a structural type. All of its data members are public, and those two members (`int` and `int`) are themselves structural types.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm copying exactly what g++ said: 'error: ‘std::pair<int, int>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter because it is not structural'. For me, it didn't work with c++20, either.

Comment: @lorro: And I'm reading the standard, and there is nothing in the C++20 standard that would cause `pair<int, int>` to not be structural. If GCC is giving you this error in a C++20 build, then it is wrong to do so.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I'm aware of that. Hence very likely compiler / library bug. Probably worth reporting.

Comment: Ok, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), "literal class type" can be passed since C++20 only. So this answers my question. Though GCC doesn't give me your error (or any error in C++20), so I'm not sure what version you're using.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've included an alternative solution that uses compile-time pairs and proves my theory (i.e., it works).

Comment: @Nelfeal with gcc 10.2.1, `--std=c++20`, I'm receiving the error.